# web.config match and redirect urls from root file to folder

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, web-config, http-redirect

I moved my blog posts from the root of my website to a folder. I want to include a rule in my site's web.config that redirects permanently the posts from their old root location to the new folder location.

All posts have filenames of the following form, a form no other files on my website have, and the filenames are the same in the new folder location as they were in the old root location:
ROJR####.htm    *or*   ROJR####-#.htm

As a newbie to both web.config and regex, I am struggling to code accurately the pattern for the match url, as well as the pattern for the redirected url.

My current code is:

```
<rule name="redirect ROJR" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(ROJR\d\d\d\d-?\d?\.htm)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="^OJRU\/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Here are my questions:

*Match URL:*  Did I accurately describe the pattern?  And will the pattern look *only* for posts previously located in the root (and not find the moved posts with the same name in the OJRU folder)?

*Redirected URL:* Did I redirect accurately the old URLs to the new location?

> FROM:  example.com/ROJR####-#.htm
> TO:  example.com/OJRU/ROJR####-#.htm
> *and*
> FROM: example.com/ROJR####.htm
> TO: example.com/OJRU/ROJR####.htm

Thanks for your help.